# Intent.Action_Send and ShareCompat.IntentBuilder dialog is missing app icons

Tags: android

I have the following code that starts a intent to send email message

```
@Override
public void onPostExecute(File outfile) {
    ProgressDialogRequestIcons d1 = (ProgressDialogRequestIcons) fm.findFragmentByTag("DIALOG_F2");
    d1.dialogDismiss();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(outfile);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { getString(R.string.app_email) });
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Icon Support for" + " " + this.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I am using " + Build.DEVICE + " with Android version " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
    this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send eMail.."));
}
```

However when the dialog pops up to choose the app to send it shows with no icons liket this

[image]

So then i tried another method as follows but still have same issue.

```
public void startEmailIntentWithPackage(File icon_request){
    try{
        ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
                .setType("application/zip")
                .addStream(Uri.parse("file://" + icon_request.getAbsolutePath()))
                .addEmailTo(getString(R.string.app_email))
                .setSubject("Icon Support for" + " " + this.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setText("I am using " + Build.DEVICE + " with Android version " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE)
                .setChooserTitle("Send Email..")
                .startChooser();
    }
    catch (Exception ignored)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Since that's not under your control, I would assume it's a device issue. Do other apps on that device exhibit the same behavior?

Comment: No they don't. Thats what i thought at first too. Same device i used a similar app and it comes up correctly. My Nexus 5 does the same thing. The screen above is from my Droid Maxx on 4.4

Comment: This screen was taken from a different app that does the same thing. https://www.dropbox.com/s/f2mck621n713e0m/2014-03-11%2019.51.11.png

Comment: I finally figured out why this was happening but still dont know how to fix it. When i launch the email intent im also launching an Async Task. When its finished the icons are showing up. How can i fix this?

Comment: Perhaps your task is doing too much work on the main application thread (`onProgressUpdate()` or `onPostExecute()`).

Comment: Async task is a Void, Void, Void with just doInBackground running. Its an http client sending nameValuePairs to my php

Comment: Then perhaps you are invoking it via `execute()`, rather than `executeOnExecutor()`, and it is blocking an `AsyncTask` that `ShareCompat` uses. If you are not using `onPostExecute()`, you are better served using just a plain `Thread`, not an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Thank you so much. i love it when you answer my questions you are such a knowledgeable person. i subscribe to your book and read it all the time. btw i fixed this by using a  Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable() { method. if you put your last comment as an answer i will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the annoyances with `AsyncTask` is the move back to serialized execution by default, which started in earnest in API Level 13. This gets worse when libraries use `AsyncTask` internally... and do not themselves use `executeOnExecutor()` to opt into a thread pool.

My guess is that:

- You used `execute()` to start a task
- `ShareCompat` used `execute()` to start another task... which then blocked until the first task completed

The solutions are either to:

- Use `executeOnExecutor()` yourself, or
- Use a plain `Thread`, particularly if you do not need the `onPostExecute()` or `onProgressUpdate()` pieces of `AsyncTask`

Comment: i fixed this by using a Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable() { method. Thank you so much!